# Solution to quotient differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We have the following differential equation

> $$ \frac {dy}{dx}= \frac {(xy+3x-y-3)}{(xy-4x+6y-24)}$$

which we are solving for $ (\frac {x+6}{y+3})^7$.

I'm not really sure how to do this problem. I tried separation of variables which is the only technique we've learned so far but keep getting bogged down in the algebra. How do I solve this?

Comment: **Hint:** Factor the numerator and also factor the denominator and then see that it is a Separable Equation.

Answer (score 5):

Hint...you have $$\frac{y-4}{y+3}dy=\frac{x-1}{x+6}dx$$